# Python: Need to overlap the actual data in a boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using this code to plot my data in boxplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

random_dists = ['Overlap', 'Non overlap', ]

Overlap= [6,6,5,1,3,4,4,3]
non_overlap= [1,2,6,6,1,3,3,3,3,3,5,2,2]


data = [
    Overlap,
    non_overlap
]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('A Boxplot Example')
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.075, right=0.95, top=0.9, bottom=0.25)

# bp = ax1.boxplot(data, notch=0, sym='+', vert=1, whis=1.5)
bp = ax1.boxplot(data)
plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color='black')
plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color='black')
plt.setp(bp['fliers'], color='red', marker='+')


    
    
# Add a horizontal grid to the plot, but make it very light in color
# so we can use it for reading data values but not be distracting
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey',
               alpha=0.5)

# Hide these grid behind plot objects
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax1.set_title('overlap and non_overlap against mRS')
# ax1.set_xlabel('Distribution')
# ax1.set_ylabel('Value')

# Now fill the boxes with desired colors
box_colors = ['darkkhaki', 'royalblue']
num_boxes = len(data)
medians = np.empty(num_boxes)
for i in range(num_boxes):
    box = bp['boxes'][i]
    boxX = []
    boxY = []
    for j in range(5):
        boxX.append(box.get_xdata()[j])
        boxY.append(box.get_ydata()[j])
    box_coords = np.column_stack([boxX, boxY])
    # Alternate between Dark Khaki and Royal Blue
    ax1.add_patch(Polygon(box_coords, facecolor=box_colors[i % 2]))
    # Now draw the median lines back over what we just filled in
    med = bp['medians'][i]
    medianX = []
    medianY = []
    for j in range(2):
        medianX.append(med.get_xdata()[j])
        medianY.append(med.get_ydata()[j])
        ax1.plot(medianX, medianY, 'k')
    medians[i] = medianY[0]
    # Finally, overplot the sample averages, with horizontal alignment
    # in the center of each box
    ax1.plot(np.average(med.get_xdata()), np.average(data[i]),
             color='w', marker='*', markeredgecolor='k')

    
# Set the axes ranges and axes labels
ax1.set_xlim(0.5, num_boxes + 0.5)
top = 10 #y-axis
bottom = 0 #y-axis
ax1.set_ylim(bottom, top)
ax1.set_xticklabels(np.repeat(random_dists, 1),
                    rotation=45, fontsize=8)

pos = np.arange(num_boxes) + 1

# Finally, add a basic legend
fig.text(0.80, 0.08, 'Overlap',
         backgroundcolor=box_colors[0], color='black', weight='roman',
         size='x-small')
fig.text(0.80, 0.045, 'Non overlap',
         backgroundcolor=box_colors[1],
         color='white', weight='roman', size='x-small')
fig.text(0.80, 0.015, '*', color='white', backgroundcolor='silver',
         weight='roman', size='medium')
fig.text(0.815, 0.013, ' Average Value', color='black', weight='roman',
         size='x-small')

plt.show()
```

What i need is overlap the data into it as a scatter plot just like the picture from this [link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/fonnesbeck/5850463) [image]

I really try hard to use the code on the link and try to search on overstack to find a solution but i'm not that good in coding, also i try using seaborn library but i always get an error that: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' and couldn't fix it
so please any one can help ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `plt.boxplot()` allows plotting most of these elements standard.
Means will be drawn if `showmeans` is set to `True`. Its properties can be controlled via the `meanprops` dictionary. When setting `patch_artist=True`, instead of just the outline, a filled box will be drawn, `boxprops` controls how they look.

To draw the scatter plot on top, just call `ax1.scatter`. The x-positions can be jittered randomly via `i + np.random.uniform(-0.4, 0.4)`. To force them on top of boxplot, their z-order can be changed.

As the fliers are also part of the scatter data, it probably makes sense to leave them out (`showfliers=False`).

To create a legend, you can collect handles to all desired elements and pass them to `ax1.legend()`. Note that your boxplots already get labels in the x-axis, so having them also in the legend might be a bit superfluous.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

random_dist_names = ['Overlap', 'Non overlap']
overlap = [6, 6, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3]
non_overlap = [1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2]
data = [overlap, non_overlap]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('A Boxplot Example')
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.075, right=0.95, top=0.9, bottom=0.25)

box_colors = ['darkkhaki', 'royalblue']
scatter_colors = ['purple', 'crimson']
legend_handles = []
for i, (values, box_color, scatter_color) in enumerate(zip(data, box_colors, scatter_colors), start=1):
    bp = ax1.boxplot(values, positions=[i], showmeans=True, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False,
                     boxprops={'edgecolor': 'black', 'facecolor': box_color},
                     whiskerprops={'color': 'black'},  # flierprops={'color': 'red', 'marker': '+'},
                     medianprops={'color': 'lime', 'linewidth': 2, 'linestyle': ':'},
                     meanprops={'markerfacecolor': 'w', 'marker': '*', 'markeredgecolor': 'k', 'markersize': 10})
    if i == 1:
        legend_handles.append(bp['means'][0])
    legend_handles.append(bp['boxes'][0])
    ax1.scatter(i + np.random.uniform(-0.4, 0.4, len(values)), values, color=scatter_color, alpha=0.5, zorder=3)

ax1.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax1.set_title('overlap and non_overlap against mRS')

ax1.set_xlim(0.5, len(data) + 0.5)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax1.set_xticklabels(random_dist_names, rotation=0, fontsize=8)
ax1.legend(legend_handles, ['Mean'] + random_dist_names, bbox_to_anchor=[1, -0.1], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that you have very few data points, and they all have integer values, which makes the red dots appear in horizontal lines.

PS: To create something similar with Seaborn, the data has to be organized more similar to a pandas dataframe. Such a dataframe would have one column with all the values, and one column with the category.

The legend can be created more automatically. To also get the means into the legend, a label has to be assigned to the mean via `meanprops={..., 'label': 'Mean'}`. Unfortunately, this creates one legend entry for every box. These can be skipped by first getting all the legend entries with `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` and taking subarrays of the handles and labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

random_dist_names = ['Overlap', 'Non overlap']
overlap = [6, 6, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3]
non_overlap = [1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2]
data_names = np.repeat(random_dist_names, [len(overlap), len(non_overlap)])
data_values = np.concatenate([overlap, non_overlap])

ax = sns.boxplot(x=data_names, y=data_values, hue=data_names, palette=['darkkhaki', 'royalblue'],
                 dodge=False, showfliers=False, showmeans=True,
                 meanprops={'markerfacecolor': 'w', 'marker': '*', 'markeredgecolor': 'k', 'markersize': 10, 'label': 'Mean'})
sns.stripplot(x=data_names, y=data_values, color='red', alpha=0.4)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
skip_pos = len(random_dist_names) - 1
ax.legend(handles[skip_pos:], labels[skip_pos:], bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, -0.05), loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: is there a way to put each points with different color in term of differentiation between the points?

Comment: yes this is it, but how do i specify color for each column

Comment: I updated the code to include a color for the scatter dots into the loop.